# Why JTextArea appears small when using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

I am building a very simple application with Java Swing, using GridBagLayout. My goal is to make two identical panels, one to the left and one to the right of the JFrame, both containing a JTextArea, a JLabel and a JButton.

My problem is that the JTextArea shows up very small and not spanning the entire width of its panel. I am sure I am confusing/forgetting some constraints, but I could not figure out which ones even after extensive reading online.

Please also note that I have tried a different constructor for the JTextArea, specifying the number of rows and columns, but the result does not change.

[What I see when running my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsCgV.png)

Here below is the code I have now (divided in three classes: App, MainFrame and Panel).

App.java

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainFrame.java

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private Panel leftPanel;
private Panel rightPanel;

    public MainFrame() {

        super("App");

        leftPanel = new Panel();
        rightPanel = new Panel();

        layoutComponents();

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private void layoutComponents() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;

        add(leftPanel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;

        add(rightPanel, gc);

    }

}
```

Panel.java

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public Panel() {

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        label = new JLabel("Select destination folder");
        button = new JButton("Output");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc2 = new GridBagConstraints();

        // First Row //

        gc2.gridx = 0;
        gc2.gridy = 0;

        gc2.weightx = 2;
        gc2.weighty = 1;

        gc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), gc2);

        // Second Row //

            // Label //

        gc2.gridx = 0;
        gc2.gridy = 1;

        gc2.weightx = 1;
        gc2.weighty = 0.1;

        gc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        
        add(label, gc2);     
        
            // Button //

        gc2.gridx = 1;
        gc2.gridy = 1;

        gc2.weightx = 1;
        gc2.weighty = 0.1;

        gc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        add(button, gc2);

    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance for helping me with this problem.

Comment: To make jtextarea large, use setPrreferedsize method

Comment: @jfran may mean well, but their advice is wrong and will lead to bad behavior, especially when you place the text area within a JScrollPane where it is usually placed. This will prevent the text area from being scrollable. Instead, *never* set a Swing text component's preferred size but instead set its column and row properties

Comment: This is easily accomplished by calling the JTextArea's constructor that accepts 2 int parameters, for rows and columns

Comment: Actually I did try using the constructor (for JTextArea) specifying the rows and columns, but it did not work. Neither did adding "textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,150));", which I have just tried.

Comment: Where do you pack() your JFrame?

Comment: *"Actually I did try .."* Try posting a [mre]. In an MRE, there is no need to add the panel twice, or the other components not involved with the problem. A general tip on this one though is, ignore @JFan, listen to Hovercraft Full Of Eels.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your replies, very useful and appreciated! I have made the following edits to the code: changed the constructor of the JTextArea (textArea = new JTextArea(30,20);) and called the pack method in the MainFrame constructor. I have one last perplexity. While now it is much larger, still the JTextArea does not span the whole width of the panel (from the beginning of the label to the end of the button), notwithstanding I set the GridBagConstraints attribute "weightx" at 2 before inserting the TextArea and at 1 before inserting the Label and Button. Any ideas why?

Comment: *the JTextArea does not span the whole width of the panel (from the beginning of the label to the end of the button),* - you need to specify the `gridwidth` contstraint with a value of 2 for the text area (you will then need to reset it back to 1 for the other components). Also, why are you using a text area? Looks to me like you are prompting for a file name which should probably be displayed in a JTextField. Read the `Specifying Constraints` section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr It works!! Thank you very much! I am using a TextArea because my idea was to export the text entered by the user to a .txt file.

Comment: @andy_07 Text is text. It doesn't matter if it comes from a JTextField, JTextArea or JTextPane, it can still be written to a file. Use the appropriate component to display the data. If it is possible for the data to have multiple line then you use a JTextArea. If it is only ever a single line then use a JTextField.

Comment: @camickr I understand the point you are making here. Thanks!

Comment: @JFan: please delete your misleading and incorrect comment

Comment: *"It works!!"* Congrats on getting it sorted. :) Now you might enter an answer below, to help others solve the same problem later, or more simply, delete the entire question using the link below the tags.